# XOR recursive function returning values besides zero and one

Tags: c, debugging, xor

I am working on an assignment for my comsci class. However, I'm not having an issue with what the assignment is asking. The idea is to randomly generate numbers based on a seed by selecting specific bit locations (taps), shifting the seed to the left 1, and then use XOR logic to append either a 0 or 1 to the right end of the seed. The base case is a seed of 6 (0110) and then taps 3 and 2. Tap3 = 0, Tap2 = 1, 0 XOR 1 = 1. Then 6 (0110) shifts left and becomes 12 (1100), lastly the 1 is added and the value becomes 13 (1101). The taps remain in place until the desired amount of values are printed. Meaning after this Tap3 = 1 and Tap2 = 0.

```
int tapShift(int tempSeed, int tap){//shifts seed over to the desired tap and returns that tap value. 0 or 1
  int bitVal = tempSeed >> tap;
  bitVal == bitVal & 1;
  return bitVal;}

int xorTaps(int taps[], int length, int tempSeed){
  if(length == 0){
    return tapShift(tempSeed, 31);//return a-1 tap after all input taps.
  }else{//returns the binary value of selected tap to recursively determine XOR of taps.
    return tapShift(tempSeed, taps[length-1])^xorTaps(taps,--length, tempSeed);} }
```

The issue i'm having is that xorTaps is returning values such as 6,7,5,3, just not values I thought could be returned. I've been looking at this for a few hours now without progress, hence why I decided to ask for help. I call xorTaps farther down in my code.

```
int feedback = xorTaps(taps, i , tempSeed);
```

A tap of the n-1 bit must always be considered as apart of the assignment.  Meaning a  tap for slot 31 of the 32 bit seed is always evaluated in the XOR arithmetic.

Comment: You should use better formatting technique, for example close braces on their own line

Answer (score 0):

Well. I asked my sibling who is much more adept at debugging. 20 minutes later I had mistakenly typed
bitVal == tempSeed & 1.
The correct code is    bitVal = tempSeed & 1.

Comment: You have a typo bug in your self-answer.  It seems you have a problem with typing things.  I suggest that you don't try to correct it - the result may be recursive:)